# Is app web deleted when a SharePoint app is removed?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Is app web deleted when a SharePoint app or app instance is removed? 
Site owner can remove an app instance. App would be still available in app catalog and app can have instances in other site collections. Would app web and any data stored in app web get deleted too?

Comment: Yes it would. The app web is what is deleted when the app is deleted

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks for the direct answer. Can you please provide a reference and answer below so that I can mark it as answer? I am looking for a reference, hopefully from microsoft, stating that app web would be deleted (not to  recycle bin) when an app is removed. Technet article waqas below gave does not state about that app web is deleted.

Comment: His source is the only source you need: When you remove an app the data will no longer be available

Comment: @RobertLindgren Here is the microsoft source that I was looking for...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179933(v=office.15).aspx ,it explicitly states "If the app for SharePoint includes an app web, the app web is deleted."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, When you remove an app, the data for that app will no longer be available.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I am looking for a reference, hopefully microsoft, stating that app web would be deleted (not to recycle bin) when an app is removed. I am not interested in how to remove an app but internal on what happens when a app is removed. I had no luck on google search.